# Setting up Spring Security Kerberos - spn and keytab

Tags: java, kerberos, gssapi, spring-security-kerberos, keytab

I'm trying to get the sample spring security kerberos application running, before I try and integrate it into my actual application. This is the app I'm running: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos/tree/master/spring-security-kerberos-samples/sec-server-win-auth/src/main

I have setup the spn, and created the keytab, when running the application, and am attempting to access using chrome, I get back an error 500

Which on the server console shows up as:

```
Negotiate Header was invalid: 
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: 
GSSContext name of the context initiator is null
at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:253)
```

I can see from the code that this happens when `getSrcName()` from the `GSSContext` returns null.

Fow now I'm running just on my laptop, to try and get it working. The java process that's running the spring app is running under the same windows account that I use to login. DNS is configured so that I can access my laptop using `laptop-name.mycompany.com` Here's what I did for the spn and keytab:

`setspn -A HTTP/laptop-name.mycompany.com:8080 myWindowsUsername`

`ktpass -princ HTTP/laptop-name.mycompany.com:8080@MYCOMPANY.COM -pass password123 -mapuser myWindowsUsername@mycompany.com -out keytab.keytab -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL`

Inside of the java `security` directory I have added `krb5.conf` which contains the following:

```
[Libdefaults]
 permitted_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 rc4-hmac aes256-cts aes128-cts des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
 default_tgs_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 rc4-hmac aes256-cts aes128-cts des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
 default_tkt_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 rc4-hmac aes256-cts aes128-cts des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
 dns_lookup_kdc = true
 dns_lookup_realm = false

[Domain_realm]
 mycompany.com = MYCOMPANY.COM
 .mycompany.com = MYCOMPANY.COM
```

I'm not sure if it is a problem, but when I use kinit to validate the keytab I see this at the bottom of the output

```
Looking for keys for: -V@MYCOMPANY.COM
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23 23 18 17 16.
Exception: krb_error 0 Do not have keys of types listed in default_tkt_enctypes available; only have keys of following type:  No error
KrbException: Do not have keys of types listed in default_tkt_enctypes available; only have keys of following type:
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.EType.getDefaults(EType.java:280)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.build(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:261)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:315)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:361)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.<init>(Kinit.java:219)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.main(Kinit.java:113)
```

The output also suggests that the prinipal is `-V@MYCOMPANY.COM` Which doesn't seem right.

I'm still somewhat of a novice around usage of keytabs and the GSS api. I'm not sure whether this is a problem with my keytab generation, the spn setup or something about my system configuration, any help would very much apprechiated.

Comment: Check keytab content with `klist -k <keytab-file> -e` on Linux and `ktab.exe -l -k <keytab-file> -e` _(shipped with JRE)_ on Windows

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter it is listing 5 lines each for: `HTTP/laptop-name.mycompany.com:8080` and `HTTP/laptop-name.mycompany.com` and `HTTP/laptop-name:8080` and `HTTP/laptop-name` all with the same kvno

Comment: _"when I use kinit to validate the keytab"_ > what is the actual command line you are using: something like `kinit -kt <keytab-file> HTTP/laptop-name.mycompany.com`?

Comment: I'm running `kinit -k -t <keytab-file> HTTP/laptop-name.mycompany.com@MYCOMPANY.COM`